# How to filter collections using a custom nunjucks filter in an eleventy template?

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

I'm new to both e11y and nunjucks and I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

I need to filter a collection to keep only items matching a condition. The `selectattr` filter would be perfect, but in [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#selectattr-only-the-single-argument-form) it only works with booleans unfortunately.

In a related [eleventy issue](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/910) it is recommended to create a custom filter, but when I add one (called `user_id`) the site crashes, saying `test not found: user_id`.

Here's what I've done for the moment to try and make it work:

```js
// .eleventy.js
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
  // beginning of config…
  eleventyConfig.addFilter("user_id", function(el) {
    return el.user_id;
  });
  // …end of config
}
```

```
// pages/index.njk
{% set collection = [{user_id: 1, name: "one"}, {user_id: 2, name: "two"}] %}
{{ collection | select("user_id", 1) }}
```

Here's the crash log:

```bash
[11ty] Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
[11ty] 1. Having trouble rendering njk template ./pages/index.njk (via TemplateContentRenderError)
[11ty] 2. (./pages/index.njk)
[11ty]   Error: test not found: user_id (via Template render error)
[11ty] 
[11ty] Original error stack trace: Template render error: (./pages/index.njk)
[11ty]   Error: test not found: user_id
[11ty]     at Object._prettifyError (~/Sites/site/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:36:11)
[11ty]     at ~/Sites/site/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:563:19
[11ty]     at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (~/Sites/site/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:111:3)
[11ty]     at Template.render (~/Sites/site/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:552:10)
[11ty]     at ~/Sites/site/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/Engines/Nunjucks.js:416:14
[11ty]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[11ty]     at ~/Sites/site/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/Engines/Nunjucks.js:415:14
[11ty]     at Template._render (~/Sites/site/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/TemplateContent.js:473:28)
[11ty]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[11ty]     at async TemplateMap.populateContentDataInMap (~/Sites/site/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/TemplateMap.js:494:13)
```

Why would a custom filter added in `.eleventy.js` be unavailable in templates? Are tests different from filters? Or does `select` only work with nunjucks default tests?
But most importantly, how can I filter a collection to select only items where a property matches a given value? I'm very surprised that it's not natively available.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `select` doesn't allow passing custom filters. Custom filters need to be called directly, like so:

```js
eleventyConfig.addFilter("filter", function (arr=[], key="", value) {
  return arr?.filter(item => item[key] === value);
});

{% set collection = [{user_id: 1, name: "one"}, {user_id: 2, name: "two"}] %}
{{ collection | filter("user_id", 1) | dump }}

=> [{user_id: 1, name: "one"}]
```